# Upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 to 15.1 and I end up at a command line at restart. What do I do now?

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade

[This problem did not go away on its own and it wasn't a typo correction that solved it either. That being said I understand if you delete it b/c of the poor solution explanation.  In a nut shell the problem was solved by attempting to update and then following the directions provided by the terminal.]

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 to 15.1 and now when I start my laptop I end I up at the command line. I don't know what to do to get into the operating system I thought I was installing.

My screen says:

```
Ubuntu 15.10 inspiron tty1

Inspiron login : mike
Password: 
Last login: Sat Jun 18 00:23:31 EDT 2016 on tty1
Mike@inspiron:~$
```

I know this question might seem vague but any help is appreciated!

Comment: `startx`  might get you a more familiar GUI, but if that would, it would probably already do so during startup as well. Why did you upgrade from supported 14.04 to 15.10 for which the support ends this month? You should try to install 16.04 alongside your current installation in a new partition and move the data over from your old 14.04/15.10 partition

Comment: I was under the impression I could upgrade to 15.1 then to 16.04 from there. I don't want to add any more partitions

Answer (score 2):

I've solved the issue. At the command line I entered apt-get update and it responded there's a problem with something (sorry I should have taken notes) and then suggested to enter something at the command line.

I'm under the impression that my computer went to sleep before the install was done and the actions I was told to take resolved the problem.

I believe they had something to do with resolvconf

I sincerely apologize for this lack of a solution but I didn't expect my actions to solve the problem.

Please delete this if it's totally useless.